# How can I get values from a Google Sheets in Dialogflow?

Tags: google-sheets, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Im kinda new in Dialogflow and now I am trying to make a chatbot for my own webpage. I was doing research about my question but I don't get any solution to my problem.

The thing is, I have a file in Google Sheets with the name of my users and the ID of all of them. I want to ask for the ID of the user and then get the name variable in all of the chat.

Example:

**Bot:** Hi, tell me your ID
**User:** 10289432
**Bot:** Hi Jason, what can i help you today?

Is that posible with the data in a sheets?

Note: I can't use fulfillment because i have a free account in Dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

Without fulfillment this isn't possible. You need to use a webhook to authenticate with Google sheets and call the API to retrieve data from a sheet. During development you can create a free webhook by using a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which creates a public https endpoint that targets a localhost address, but if you want to put this live somewhere you need to host it somewhere.